# Directory owner changing by themselves

Tags: permissions

My  root and usr directories changes to user and group 1023 by themselves and I don't know why.
I'm  using Ubuntu gnome 16.04 mainly, but also Windows 7, Remix Os and Slitaz.
I think it could be done by Remix (android) when I load it, so it takes a look to other harddrives by media rescan....
But I need an explanation please.
Sorry about my english :)

Comment: If you suspect that the problematic action is performed by an operating system that is **not Ubuntu** then your question is likely **not about Ubuntu** and thus off topic on Ask **Ubuntu**.

Answer (score 0):

1023 is the `id` of a non-existing user. And not the main/sudo user of your current active operating system (that is almost always 1000).

The 1023 normally gets mapped against `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/group` and the system picks the name and group for that id from there. If there is not one the id is shown.

Find out who 1023 is on any of your systems (except Windows, I think that will show "nobody" as user name).